# Select a single client certificate when making a call

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient, x509certificate2

I am writing a client library that is expected to call one server that supports several types of authentication. The server's API has a few main groups of methods (admin, user, workflow orchestration...), each group has a different authentication (different certificate or token).
When it comes to tokens they are easily replaced between requests, but certificate are another story.

Q: how do I manually pick which certificate would be used for a request?

I would rather not create multiple instances of HttpClient, if possible.
WebRequestHandler doesn't appear to have a way to select one, instead, it passes the whole collection to the HttpWebRequest it creates and the method that does that is internal

```
    var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
    webRequestHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;     
    webRequestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert1);
    webRequestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert2);
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler))
    {
        using (var httpReq = new HttpRequestMessage()){
            // HOW DO I FORCE cert1 for this request only?
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpReq); 
            return response;
        }

    }
```

Comment: So typically how client cert auth works is that the server will say 'here's my cert, now provide me a client cert that matches X' where X usually is a chain of issuing CAs and sometimes Key Usage parameters. What this means is that if you load two different certs into the HttpClientHandler (or webrequesthandler in your case) then the underlying framework should pick the right one for you. Now if BOTH certs match that general criteria (e.g. you have one service, admin and normal users and both certs need to be chosen by endpoint) then (continued)

Comment: I guess you will HAVE to use mutliple HttpClients, and in .net core you can use IHttpClientFactory for this, e.g. see here: https://damienbod.com/2019/09/07/using-certificate-authentication-with-ihttpclientfactory-and-httpclient/

Comment: @zaitsman typically... doesn't apply to my project :) the project I work on deals with a lot of certificates, the size of a big CA probably. The reason I need this is to avoid having too many HttpClient instances floating around, but I guess I'll have to deal with it.

Comment: if you have many certificates, and they are issued by many CAs, you do not need to handle it, the framework will.

Comment: my project is sort of CA, the certificates are internal and the objective is to test various possible combinations of cert and services. For example, 10 certificates and 10 possible APIs would require 100 calls. I don't really expect my scenario to be easy to optimize because it's quite unusual :)

Comment: Ahm, it kind of is, just get a different CA cert for each API, then load all client certs issued by those CAs into one http client, and then the HttpClient will pick the right one for you.

Comment: the goal is actually to pick all of them one by one - to make sure the wrong ones don't work

Comment: you won't be able to do that in c# httpclient i don't think. I mean, you can add the wrong cert to httpclient but it won't be presented to the server anyway if it is not from the right CA.

Comment: You can perhaps write your own Http Client based off of TCP sockets but it's a lot of work to test that SSL works correctly. Sounds a bit like a X-Y problem.